# SQL Server PIVOT with dateadd()

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot, fingerprint, dateadd

I am trying to generate a report from a database called BioStar, which comes from  Suprema Finger Print machine. Here is a sample of the data I have:

```
nDateTime           sUserName           department Event EventName nUserID
---------           ---------            --------- -----  --------  ------
2015-08-15 07:52:37.000 Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem  Nursing   0   In      75
2015-08-15 16:26:14.000 Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem  Nursing   1   Out     75
2015-08-16 07:59:18.000 Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem  Nursing   0   In      75
2015-08-16 07:59:25.000 Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem  Nursing   0   In      75
2015-08-16 16:06:24.000 Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem  Nursing   1   Out     75
2015-08-16 16:06:30.000 Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem  Nursing   1   Out     75
```

This is the stored procedure I am using:

```
    ALTER proc [dbo].[viewLogInfo]

@UserIdn int,
@startDate smalldatetime,
@endDate smalldatetime

as
--exec viewLogInfo '75','2015-08-15','2015-08-25'

select  DATEADD(s,el.nDateTime,'1970-01-01') nDateTime, sUserName,ud.sName,el.nTNAEvent,dek.sEventName,nUserID from tb_Event_Log el
join TB_USER u on el.nUserID=u.nUserIdn
join TB_EVENT_DATA ed on el.nEventIdn=ed.nEventIdn
join TB_TA_DEVICE_EVENT_KEY dek on el.nTNAEvent=dek.nKeyIdn
join TB_USER_DEPT ud on u.nDepartmentIdn=ud.nDepartmentIdn
where el.nUserID=@UserIdn and (DATEADD(s,el.nDateTime,'1970-01-01')  between @startDate and @endDate)

order by el.nEventLogIdn
```

I want the report to look like this:

```
nDateTime           sUserName               IN            OUT
---------           ---------               --            ---
2015-08-15          Hamdy Mokhtar Moelem    07:52:37      16:26:14
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
USE [BioStar]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[viewLogInfo12]    Script Date: 09/11/2015 20:42:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[viewLogInfo12]

--@UserIdn int,
@startDate smalldatetime,
@endDate smalldatetime


as
-- exec viewLogInfo12 '2015-08-01','2015-08-31'
select sUserName,departmentName,event01,nUserID,nDateTime2,ev1,
        [in] as inTime, [out] as outTime
        e

from

(
select  sUserName,ud.sName departmentName,el.nTNAEvent event01,dek.sEventName,dek.sEventName ev1,nUserID,DATEADD(s,el.nDateTime,'1970-01-01') nDateTime1,DATEADD(s,el.nDateTime,'1970-01-01') nDateTime2 from tb_Event_Log el
join TB_USER u on el.nUserID=u.nUserIdn
join TB_EVENT_DATA ed on el.nEventIdn=ed.nEventIdn
join TB_TA_DEVICE_EVENT_KEY dek on el.nTNAEvent=dek.nKeyIdn
join TB_USER_DEPT ud on u.nDepartmentIdn=ud.nDepartmentIdn
where  (DATEADD(s,el.nDateTime,'1970-01-01')  between @startDate and @endDate)

 ) m

pivot 

( max(sEventName) 
for sEventName in ([in],[out]) ) pvt
```

Both inTime and outTime are null.
Please help.

Comment: In and Out are not column names yet, I think you need to put single quote marks around them in 
`( max(sEventName) for sEventName in (['in'],['out']) ) `

Comment: @NaNey I have tried putting ['in'] and ['out'], it is is giving null values. Any other suggestions.

Comment: @InAbuukar : Can you please create sqlfiddle with sample data and query?

Comment: @DarkKnight thank you for your help. The query you gave me is producing the same  result as the previous one given by NaNey. Both In and Out columns are null. Regarding sqlfiddle, I have generated scripts of my database, but did not understand how to upload it to sqlfiddle. Do I have to upload all tables that are joined in the stored procedure. Sorry for the delay, I have problem with my internet connection. Thank you.

Comment: @InAbuukar : I created a fiddle with the query i have given in answer and working.. please take a look.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3218/1
added link in answer too.

Comment: @DarkKnight Thank you, I will try. By they way here is a text file in Google Drive I have uploaded (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3WLcdc2dwgbHRGNDN5cEF5Z28/view?usp=sharing). Please have a look. Thank you. By the way, all date and time in the database are integer. Does that change anything regarding the solution

Comment: @DarkKnight here is a backup of the database (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_3WLcdc2dwgbFU3ejF3OEQyR1E/view?usp=sharing). Please have a look. Stored procedure viewLogInfoSample3 is the last one

Comment: @InAbuukar : did you get a chance to check fiddle in my answer?

Comment: @DarkKnight I had the chance to see it. It is working. Thank you. The difference is that you have created a table with the data and in my case I am getting null values. I thought if I gave you my database itself, you may have the chance to see what mistake I am making.

Comment: @DarkKnight Thank you for your effort and time. I was new to SQL Server and I was on exploratory task to create a pivot table. I only changed the column heading from [In] and [Out] to [0] and [1] respectively and the FOR  IN column from seventname to ntnaevent and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query inside the cte is query inside your procedure. You can also insert data into temporary table instead of using CTE.

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    --This is your query
    SELECT Dateadd(s, el.ndatetime, '1970-01-01') nDateTime, 
           susername, 
           ud.sname, 
           el.ntnaevent, 
           dek.seventname, 
           nuserid  
    FROM   tb_event_log el 
           JOIN tb_user u 
             ON el.nuserid = u.nuseridn 
           JOIN tb_event_data ed 
             ON el.neventidn = ed.neventidn 
           JOIN tb_ta_device_event_key dek 
             ON el.ntnaevent = dek.nkeyidn 
           JOIN tb_user_dept ud 
             ON u.ndepartmentidn = ud.ndepartmentidn 
    WHERE  el.nuserid = @UserIdn 
           AND ( Dateadd(s, el.ndatetime, '1970-01-01') BETWEEN 
                 @startDate AND @endDate ) 
)    
   --***This is where the magic happens***
    SELECT dateprt, 
           susername, 
           Min([in])  AS [In], 
           Max([out]) AS [out] 
    FROM   (SELECT Cast(ndatetime AS DATE) AS dateprt, 
                   Cast(ndatetime AS TIME) AS timeprt, 
                   * 
            FROM   CTE) pv 
           PIVOT (Max(timeprt) 
                 FOR eventname IN ([In], 
                                   [Out])) AS pvt 
    GROUP  BY dateprt, 
              susername
```

Fiddle here.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3218/1